# While function doesn't work like I want it to

Tags: c++, while-loop

Had a new problem with the while function. As easy as it sounds, I still can't wrap my head around it.

Like my last program, this one closes unexpectedly after the correct and wrong messages.
I want this to loop after entering a number, so that the program won't stop.
Thanks for the help, if any.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int X = 0; //setting the first variable
    int num; //setting the second

    while (X == 0) //this should happen whenever X is equal to 0
    {
          cout << "Type a number bigger than 3. "; //output
          X++; //This should increase X, so that the next while function can happen
    }
    while (X == 1) //again, since I increased x by one, (0+1=1 obviously) this should happen
    {
          cin >> num; //standard input
          if (num > 3) //if function: if num is bigger than three, then this should happen
          {
                  cout << "Correct! Try again!" <<endl; //output
                  X--; //Here I'm decreasing x by one, since it was 1 before, now it becomes 0. This should make the "while (X == 0)" part happen again, so that another number bigger than three can be entered
          }
                    if (num <= 3) //if function: if num is lesser than or equal to 3, this should happen
          {
                  cout << "Wrong! Try again!" <<endl; //output
                  X--; //This is supposed to work like the "X--;" before, repeating the code from "while (X==0)"
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: use a nested-while loop?

Comment: You modify X regardless of the input

Comment: and where is the return 0;?

Comment: You have a loop, followed by another loop, and then the end of the program.

Comment: You know, `while` is not a function. Also, there is `else` if the expression tested in an `if-statement` is false. Anyway, I hate over-long code-lines, and useless comments repeating the commented code.

Comment: I recommend that you step though this code using a debugger so that you can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Your first while loop serves no purpose.

Comment: Why are you using loops here at all?  Each of your loops is internally ensuring that it can only ever execute *once*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> now it becomes 0. This should make the "while (X == 0)" part happen again

Nope. While loops don't magically take effect at any point during execution of the program. You only enter a while loop when you've reached it from code above. Programs are executed top-to-bottom, generally.

You would need a loop around the *entire* program if you want to keep going round and round. Those `while`s you have now should probably be `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two `while` loops into one, `while(true)`.

Put each previous `while` body into an `if` state with the clause from the old `while` in it.

```
while(true) {
  if (X==0) {
    // the X==0- case
  } else if (X==1) {
    // the X==1 case
  }
}
```

in order to end your loop, do a `break;`.

You have to think of C++ programs as a sequence of instructions, like a recipe.  `while` just means a loop: you check the condition.  If true, you run the body.  After running the body, you check **only that** condition again, and run the body if true.  Whenever the condition is false at the start or end of the body of the `while` (the `{}` enclosed code after it), you end the loop and proceed to the next one.

The first loop runs, finishes, then the second loop runs in your code.  Once the first loop exits, you do not go back into it just because the condition becomes true.

Understanding flow control is one of the "hard" steps of learning to program, so it is ok if you find this tricky.

There are many improvements you can do your code beyond getting it working -- there is, actually, little need for `X` at all.  But baby steps!  Once you get it working, you can ponder "how could I remove the variable `X`?".

Before making such fundamental changes to your program, you should get it working, and save a copy of it so you can "go back" to the last working version.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap all that code in it's own `while` loop:

```
while (true /* or something */)
{
    while (X == 0) //this should happen whenever X is equal to 0
    {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least put your second while loop inside the first one to get it working as intended. Otherwise your program has no reason to go back again.

Nevertheless it's not a good design.